# Вывести на экран список подкаталогов заданного каталога, влоть до заданной глубины вложенности

Tags: linux, bash

Собственно, сам вопрос. Совсем не понимаю куда копать. ls -R выводит рекурсивно, без необходимой мне, глубины вложенности.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если именно `ls`, то:

```
ls -d /etc/*/*/
```

Количество слэшезвёздочек - количество уровней. Но можно и через `find`:

```
find /etc/* -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

И так, гламурненько:

```
tree -d -L 2 /etc/
```

...

Comment: все работает, правда только без звездочки, в случае с find.)